# Parsing “你如此特别，如此与众不同，是那样的特别。” into words

Tags: mandarin

> 你如此特别，如此与众不同，是那样的特别。

I have no idea how to properly separate this sentence into words.
I want to understand it word by word.

> 你 / 如此 / 特别， // 如此 / 与众不同， // 是 / 那样的 / 特别。
>
> 你 / 如此 / 特别， // 如此 / 与众不同， // 是 / 那样 / 的 / 特别。
>
> 你 / 如 / 此 / 特别， // 如 / 此 / 与众不同， // 是 / 那样的 / 特别。
>
> 你 / 如 / 此 / 特别， // 如 / 此 / 与众不同， // 是 / 那样 / 的 / 特别。
>
> My tries... :(

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a little strange, and I've just got to know the reason. It was `是那样的耀眼`, not `是那样的特别`. XD

Comment: your first try is right. "你 / 如此 / 特别， // 如此 / 与众不同， // 是 / 那样的 / 特别。"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "你(是)如此(的)特别，如此(的)与众不同。" = "You are so special (**or** *'special like this'*), so extraordinary"
>
> *(的) is optional*

The third part "是那样的特别" = "is so special (**or** *'is special like that'* )" is redundant. It should be removed and be a separate sentence.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually it was 一段 of a song, so I guess the third part is for emphasizing. However, is it syntactically valid to use ”你是...，是...。(You are ..., and are ....)“ instead of two separate sentences?

Comment: @– K. _  It is a  literary / poetic style . Also, it might be written this way for the rhyming reason  in lyrics.

Answer (score 0):

你如此特别，如此与众不同，是那样的特别。

1. 你 He
2. 如此 so
3. 特别， special, unusual, unique
4. 如此 so
5. 与 with
6. 众 masses, other people
7. 不 not
8. 同， same
9. 是 is
10. 那
11. 样的 way
12. 特别。 special, unusual, unique